# Osisoft pi data archive- How to create piServer collective

Tags: server, osisoft

I am writing a c# application that uses OSIsoft AFSDK dll (2016 version).  My application should define PI server collective and send data to this collective.
But what I'm trying to figure out is:
using C# code, how to define a PI data archive servers as a collective?   and how to configure one of them to be the primary server?

I've been searching for code examples and couldn't find any code.
Can anyone post an example or a reference to such an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a new Collective to the Known Servers Table using the next code snippet:

```
using OSIsoft.AF.PI;
PIServers myPIServers = new PIServers();
PIServer newPIServer = myPIServers.Add("NewPIServer");
```

Then you can access to PI Collective information using:

```
PICollective collective = newPIServer.Collective
```

You can consult the Live Library:

https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/T_OSIsoft_AF_PI_PIServers.htm

And also there's a very good forum for anything regarding OSIsoft PI: https://pisquare.osisoft.com/

Hope it helps!